# "The next such..." vs. "Next such..."

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article

Context: I'm compiling a list of curiosities about numbers. Tone is more colloquial than academic.

I'm not sure if I can use both **"Next such..."** and **"The next such..."**.

Example:

- 881. The first blue number. The next such number is 88464.
- 881. The first blue number. Next such number is 88464.

Omitting the "The" would be good for brevity.

I'm similarly dubious about using "The next ones are 353 and 55235" and/or "Next ones are 511 and 5331".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard usage is *the next such*. If the context is at all formal, this is the form you should use.

Articles like *the* can be omitted in casual conversation for brevity, in many cases. The frequency with which this occurs may vary by region or dialect. This is akin to speaking in sentence fragments, which are widely considered incorrect but used colloquially anyway. Speaking of which, "881." and "The first blue number." are both sentence fragments.

For what it's worth, to my ear these phrases sound awkward. I would say something like "881 is the first blue number. The next such number is 88464." or "881 is the first blue number, and the next one is 88464."

Comment: Thanks. Even to me "Next such" sounds awkward, but I had to ask. However, I think that some sentence fragments are acceptable in my case since I have this model in mind [Those Fascinating Numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=xdfTAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false) . It is a book similar to the one I'm writing. There, fragments abound.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use full sentences, saying *next such number is...* wouldn't work. That's a fragment, and it sounds a little awkward to me. The same goes for saying *next ones are...*. Keep the **the** there.

If you want brevity, you could say something like *881, the first blue number, is followed by 88464* or *881 is the first blue number, the next being 88464*.